# Magento 1.9 Localized product url keys

Tags: magento-1.9, url, localisation, product-urls, url-key

In Magento 1.9 we want to use localized product URL keys for different storeviews. The url key is a global variable and can't be changed by storeview.

**Example:**

- English: [www.example.com/en/addidas-shoes](http://www.example.com/en/addidas-shoes)
- German: [www.example.com/en/addidas-schuhe](http://www.example.com/en/addidas-schuhe)

Is there any solution or best practise for this case?

Thanks

Comment: Please check this post if it's helpful https://inchoo.net/magento/get-rewritten-product-url-in-a-different-store/